# how to handle errors when docker-compose build

Tags: docker-compose, devops

I use docker-compose to manage my docker container(service). I hope if any bad output show,docker-compose can stop immediately (I use set -e in the bash environment). But I find even though errors shows,docker-compose continue to work and generate wrong docker container (it does not work). Sometimes the wrong name of the container is born after that. I set container_name in docker-compose.yml.
how can I handle errors docker-compose jobs cause? It seems like these errors cannot be caught by the bash environment out of docker-compose.

Comment: This depends on your Dockerfile and how it is configured. Please add it to your question.

Comment: Please, add docker-compose and Dockerfile

Comment: i have,my question is how to exit build if errors come out.